# Pass email address list to SNS subscription endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

Is it possible to pass a list of email addresses as the endpoint for an SNS subscription?

I've got something like this

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources" : {
      "EmailSNSTopic": {
        "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Topic",
        "Properties" : {
          "DisplayName" : "${display_name}"
        }
      },
      "MySubscription": {
        "Type": "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
        "Properties": {
          "TopicArn" : { "Ref" : "EmailSNSTopic" },
          "Endpoint" : "foo@foo.com"
          "Protocol" : "email"
        }
      }
    },
      "Outputs" : {
        "ARN" : {
          "Description" : "Email SNS Topic ARN",
          "Value" : { "Ref" : "EmailSNSTopic" }
        }
      }
}
```

But what I'd like to do is pass a number of email addresses instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html#aws-resource-sns-subscription-properties)

> Endpoint should be a string

Cloudformation doesn't allow you to pass a list.

You dont want to have a custom resource as well.

There is one more way [Running bash commands in AWS CloudFormation templates](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/running-bash-commands-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/)

You just run [awscli command](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-resource-providers-awsutilities-commandrunner) like below

```
    Resources:
    Command:
        Type: 'AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner'
        Properties:
        Command: aws s3 ls > /command-output.txt
        Role: String
        LogGroup: String #Optional
        SubnetId: String #Optional
        SecurityGroupId: String #Optional
        KeyId: String #Optional
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @samtoddler. This makes sense.

How would I go about using this to pass the list of email addresses though? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: you just use a list of emails and iterate over them like you do in a shell script or command line. <for x in <list_emails>;do aws cli confirm subscription $x;done>

Answer (score 0):

I don’t thing it is possible using native syntax.

You might want to try aws cloud formation custom resource and pass list to lambda for execution one by one.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was hoping to avoid.